# Preselecting an attribute in a form when creating new model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to do the following:

`<%= link_to 'Create new Register', new_register_path(:date => Date.yesterday) %>`

[image]

so that when a new Register is created, the date in it is preselected to be that of yesterday (well in reality I want the Event to be preselected based on the Event from which the user clicked on the 'Create new Register' link).

i.e. If the user is on `events/2`, when they click on the link, the `registers/new` page gets loaded, and the event with the ID number 2 should be pre-selected.

Using the above code only passes that information into the URL, which is not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the params to the new object in your controller, this should auto-populate the form:

```
def new
  @regiser = Register.new(registered_at: params[:date]) #I don't know the column's name
end
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer wasn't 100% correct (that's ok, wouldn't have expected you to know it, considering you haven't seen my models), but I managed to get it to work thanks to your help. Thanks ;-)